# Compound interest formula property

Tags: calculus

I need to prove this equation:

$$\lim_{r\to0}\left((1+\frac{r}{1})^1-(1+\frac{r}{n})^n\right)=\frac{1-n}{2n}r^2$$

Lecturer gave us a hint: $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

I was thinking about expanding $(1+r/n)^n$ with Taylor series, but that gave me nothing.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You **can't** prove that equation- it isn't true!  The left side is a limit as r goes to 0 and the right side is  a function of r.  They cannot be equal.  You **can** show that, for small r, one is approximately equal to the other.  Expand the second term in a Taylor series, as you say, and you get the right side plus terms in higher powers of r.

Answer (score 0):

As given, the equation is not correct.  The limit is zero, which is also the limit of the right side as $r \to 0$.  What you have is the leading order (smallest power of $r$) term in the expansion.  The hint you are given is correct, but I don't know what use it is.  You are expected to be expanding $\left(1+\frac rn\right)^n$ using the binomial theorem.  The first two terms will cancel with the stuff before the minus sign.  The limit you are quoting will be the next term.

Answer (score 0):

*Almost as said in Ross Millikan's answer.*

If you do not use the binomial theorem, consider $$A=\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(A)=n\log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)$$ Since $\frac rn$ is small compared to $1$, use Taylor expansion (just as you though about it) $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac rn$ to get $$\log(A)=n \times \left(\frac{r}{n}-\frac{r^2}{2 n^2}+\frac{r^3}{3 n^3}+O\left(r^4\right) \right)=r-\frac{r^2}{2 n}+\frac{r^3}{3 n^2}+O\left(r^4\right)$$ Now, use Taylor again using $$A=e^{\log(A)}=1+r+\frac{(n-1) }{2 n}r^2+\frac{\left(n^2-3 n+2\right) }{6
   n^2}r^3+O\left(r^4\right)$$ This makes $$\left(1+\frac{r}{1}\right)^1-\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n=-\frac{(n-1) }{2 n}r^2-\frac{(n-2)(n-3) }{6 n^2}r^3+O\left(r^4\right)$$ If you limit the expansion to $O\left(r^3\right)$, you get your result.